# onActivityResult no shows what it should

Tags: android

I'm trying to return an EditText that has one Activity to a first Activity but when I push the button to finish de second Activity and onActivityResult is call the TextView that should show the text in the EditText save, no shos nothing.

Here's the Intent creation and the starts of the second Activity:

```
Intent myInt = new Intent(ActivityLoaderActivity.this, ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(myInt, GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Here's how I save the EditText in ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.java:

```
private void enterClicked() {

    Log.i(TAG,"Entered enterClicked()");

    // TODO - Save user provided input from the EditText field
    Editable res = mEditText.getText();
    // TODO - Create a new intent and save the input from the EditText field as an extra
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("result", res);
    // TODO - Set Activity's result with result code RESULT_OK
    setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    // TODO - Finish the Activity
    finish();
}
```

And here's is the code of onActivityResult:

```
if (requestCode == 1) {

             if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){      
                 String res = data.getStringExtra("result");
                 mUserTextView.setText(res);
             }
        }
```

In the debug mode, I can see that res has the text that I put in the EditText but it don't shos nothing in the aplication.

This is the code of mUserTextView:

```
private TextView mUserTextView;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loader_activity);

        // Get reference to the textView
        mUserTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

This is the full code of onActivityResult():

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Entered onActivityResult()");

        // TODO - Process the result only if this method received both a
        // RESULT_OK result code and a recognized request code
        // If so, update the Textview showing the user-entered text.
        if (requestCode == 1) {

             if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                 String res = data.getStringExtra("result");
                 mUserTextView.setText(res);
             }
        }

    }
```

Comment: is the GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE = 1 ??

Comment: GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE most be positive integer and ==1

Comment: Yes I have this: static private final int GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

Comment: Please add the full code for the `onActivityResult()` code

Comment: Does the `Log.i()` line show up or it doesn't call this method at all?

Comment: Yes, the Log.i() show the message

Comment: Put another `Log` line for both `requestCode` and `resultCode` and post results.

Comment: It shows both Log, I put Entered the first if and Entered the second if after the two if's and it shows the two messages

Comment: But when I try to put a Log after the String data it' does'nt show nothing, I think the problem it's the type of res in the second activity,i'm adding the code

Comment: Yes, but I was asking for the results being shown actually. Do they match what you expect?

Comment: I can't name String res, Eclipse change the type to Editable, can this make a problem in the Intent and make the TextView null?

Comment: In the Log yes it shows what it shoulds but in the aplication it doesn't show nothing and when I add a Log.i after the line when the String res is created in onACtivityResult the aplication crash

Comment: I add String resu=res.toString() and it works fine now

Answer (score 0):

```
if (requestCode == 1) {

         if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){      
             String res = getIntent.getStringExtra("result");
             mUserTextView.setText(res);
         }
    }
```

try that piece of code
and make sure GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE==1

Comment: It does'nt work:protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) ,when I try to use data =getIntent(), it's the same don't show nothing

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the same code as you describe above, it works well. Since res is really received in `onActivityResult` you should check your `mUserTextView` related code.

Comment: I edit and put the code but I think this work fine I do the same thing before and it works